# Does SumatraPdf have a configuration file?

Tags: pdf-reader, persistence

I would like to make some command line options (`-invert-colors`) permanent in my SumatraPDF installation. Is there a configuration (eg. an *ini*) file I can make SumatraPDF to use?

The [manual](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/manual.html) mentions two settings that are saved persistently into `%appdata%\SumatraPDF\sumatrapdfprefs.dat` but I can't recognize the format and it doesn't list `-invert-colors`, so I'm not sure if it's *intended* to use it as such.

Is this file documented somewhere?

I've checked the installation directory and in HKLM in regedit but found nothing relevant.

Comment: The DAT file can be opened in any text editor, but I think the problem is that only those 2 options are meant to be persisted. I suggest you post in the forum or use their bug tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify the key `(default)` located in the registry here

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\SumatraPDF.exe\Shell\Open\Command
```

by default it is like this

```
"C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" "%1" %*
```

add `-invert-colors` and sumatrapdf will always start colors inverted

:)

Answer (score 0):

Much has changed over the past 10 years. So the advanced settings.txt file is now plain text and for the one .exe portable versions, is held in the same folder. However, for installed its in "local appdata" folder.

Inversion is in default mode triggered by the `I` key but in themed modes its automatic (even if odd by implementation).

The Legacy `-invert-colors` is still respected, at present, but less useful as a command line except for a batch of blueprints or transparencies.

for the settings file structure see https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/docs/How-we-store-settings